# iTerm and terminal fail immediately on Mac - 'BrokenPipe'

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

This happened right after I tried to install `pyenv` and then virtualenvrapper. 
As soon as I open iTerminal I get a "Broken Pipe" message and macOS terminal also shuts down immediately.

- I have been trying to debug my `.bash_profile` but uncommenting one after another but without avail
- I tried updating homebrew and bash but no change (using a previously open iterm session)
- I restarted my computer with the unfortunate effect that I can't access iterm or terminal now (all old sessions closed)

I am quite at loss here now, I have no clue why this happened and how to go about fixing it without having a functioning terminal.
I'd appreciate any advice or pointers.

Comment: First of all, I would put a `set -x` in all the bash startup files which might be executed here (.bashrc, .bash_login, .bash_profile). Of course it might be that the terminal closes to quickly so that you can't even see the point where things go wrong. Then I would configure a new terminal tab which opens, say, Zsh instead of bash. From this, you should (just using the defaults) be able to start a zsh. Inside zsh, you open a bash shell. The error in this shell won't close your terminal tab and due to the `set -x`, you should be able to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Following @user1934428 advice I added `set -x` to all the bash startup files, unfortunately was still met with the same problem. Changing the startup shell in the terminal preferences didn't work.

Thankfully when using emacs ansi-term I was able to get some information/feedback message:

> The default interactive shell is now zsh. 
>   To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
>   For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.

Following the link I found that default shell has been changed to zsh Catalina. So I went and followed the instructions on the support page and changed the default shell back to bash, which fixed the problem. I am not quite sure why this problem occurred initially since the Broken Pipe Error appeared before I updated to Catalina.

Anyways changing the default shell back to bash shell fixed everything